# SharePoint Desginer versions conflict between what is mentioned inside the control panel and inside sharepoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, administration, configuration, installation, farm-admin

I have windows 7 PC , and I have download SharePoint designer 32-bit from the [Microsoft site link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35491). then I download the SP1 for it from this [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42015).

Now I wanted to check the current version for the SharePoint designer,,, but  I got these conflict versions :-

- From control panel, the version number is `15.0.4569.1506`

[image]

- while if i open SPD >> File >>Account >> About SPD i will get this version number `15.0.4615.1000`

[image]

so why I am getting conflict versions? and which one is the most accurate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal , I also have the same behavior , it's not a conflict. and the most accurate as you said,that mentioned at `SharePoint Designer`. but in fact, no one accurate than other each one represents specific information as I mentioned below.

**Explanation**

Regarding `the version number at control panel` is represented the default build number of product installation , and to ensure that check my installation version number that is identical to your version. because it's the same product.

- **Control Panel Version**

[image]

Regarding `the version number at SharePoint Designer` is the build number  of SharePoint Designer `latest update`. if you applied update as Service Pack it will be reflected at SharePoint designer not at control panel

- **SharePoint Designer Version**

[image]

Comment: but i think it is a conflict as many users might find the version inside control panel and assume it is the accurate one ...

Comment: you are right my bro , as End user perspective it's considered a conflict